# Subclassed QFrame not adjusting to it's layout

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt, pyside, qframe

I'm trying to include a horizontal frame containing a label inside a vertical frame, but even though the label is displayed it's not in the right position and it's limited to a size of a standard QLabel

This is the main class:

```
class Launcher(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFrame() #sets up window's geometry, works fine
        self.setContent() 
        self.show()

    def setContent(self):
        layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        layout.addWidget(widgets.Logo(self), 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

And this is the imported class from a "widgets" module

```
class Logo(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
        text = QLabel("PyTitle", self)
        text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        text.setFont(QFont("impact", 48))
        layout.addWidget(text, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()
```

The result is this: 
[image]

If I forcefully resize both QLabel AND QFrame, it's visible, but still in the top-left.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using QBoxLayout and not QHBoxLayout?   If you just want a bunch of widgets stacked left-to-right, use QHBoxLayout, and if you want them stacked top-to-bottom use QVBoxLayout. I would never mess with QBoxLayout. From the docs for QBoxLayout: "You will almost always want to use QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout rather than QBoxLayout because of their convenient constructors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not set a layout on a `QMainWindow`, because it already has one built in (to handle dock-widgets, the menu-bar, status-bar, etc).

Instead, set a [central-widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), and add all the widgets and layouts to that:

```
class Launcher(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def setContent(self):
        widget = widgets.Logo(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

(PS: you only need to call `show()` on the top-level window - for all other child widgets, it's redundant).